# Understanding while loop termination with System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, loops

I have this following code:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = start + 1000; // 1000 ms/sec
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            System.out.println("hello world!");
        }
    }
}
```

which gives some output of which I'm adding the end part:

```
............
............
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hel
```

From what I understand from this output is that the loop terminated in the middle of the `System.out.println("hello world!")` statement.

Which I was not expecting because I thought the `while-loop` will terminate when the `condition` will become `False`

I'm assuming that it must have happened because the `condition` became `False` when `System.out.println()` printed `"hel"`, but who was checking the `condition` in the middle of a statement, I thought the condition will be checked in the beginning of the next iteration?

I want to understand how and why it happens?

Comment: Your code didn't stop running halfway through printing a line.  You're probably hitting some sort of character limit in your display device.  How are you running your program?  How are you viewing your output?

Comment: After executing your code several times, I wasn't able to reproduce your results. There must be something else at play here. What IDE / output are you using?

Comment: @azurefrog i think if he hits that limit it will just remove the earliest lines from the top he should not stop seeing output. (for std console of ide)

Comment: I tried your code multiple time and i saw the complete output. I never cut it.

Comment: I ran your code but I added a counter++ before printing hello world. It ran successfully ~83000 times before finishing but it did finish correctly without cutting off text.

Comment: install teamviewer, give us the id and password so we can see this in action...

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is an instance of `PrintStream` and steams (in some cases) are essentially act as an I/O bridge between processes. In order to **ensure** that everything your `println` call to the stream is actually written to your console you would need to `flush` the stream. Seeming as the `System.out` is *usually* a connection between the JVM and your console (whatever that may be), it's likely that your JVM programme is terminating before your stream has *actually* been flushed to the console - hence the behaviour you are observing.

So it's **not** that a condition is being checked half-way through a println (as that just can't happen (in a thread)), but it's that you've asked for data to be sent to a stream but before that stream is able to flush the data (to the console) the JVM has terminated so it just stops doing what you've asked it to do. When the JVM unloads (as a process) it does just that - unloads and **stops existing, and stops doing whatever it was doing**.

See this article for more info: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/system-in-out-error.html specifically:

> Keep in mind though, that you should make sure to flush System.out and close the file before the JVM shuts down, to be sure that all data written to System.out is actually flushed to the file.

Though for "file", read "console" for your programme.

So to ensure flushing your programme (probably, I haven't tested so am "theoretically programming" here) becomes:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long end = start + 1000; // 1000 ms/sec
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
                System.out.println("hello world!");
            }
        } finally {
            System.out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```